# save screenshot image to file in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, http, flex4

I need the user of my Flex application to be able to save a snapshot of part of the UI to a local jpg file. I got the screenshot part down - can generate an image out of any given control. However, the only way I see to let the user save the image locally is to send to my server which would return it with the appropriate Content-Disposition.

I really hope I can avoid this silly round-trip to the server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid this round trip if you are targeting only Flash player 10. The `FileReference` class FP10 has a [save method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29) that lets you save a file to local machine; of course you still need the user's confirmation to do it.

Comment: This was new to me. I will also try this. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse the jpg file in your Flex application you could save it as Flash Cookie via `SharedObject` to the local filesystem and restore it later. In this case you must be aware of the Flash Cookie size limit which is typically set to 100KB.